# site is logging me out when navigate to different page?

Tags: users

A few things have been going on since upgrading my vps from one cpu to two and the providers explained they had to set me up on an older kernel, something about my set up not compatible on normal kernel for upgrade.

Anyway just when the site has gone live and I'm out advertising it, I came back only to notice it keeps logging me out when I navigate around.

Somehow I think this also has something to do with upgrade and with my having a subdomain because when I did the upgrade my site.com was still loading but my drupal.site.com was not until they did the switch. Then I couldn't log in as admin so found the .htaccess file had recreated itself in my drupal folder with upgrade so I had to delete it in order to log in at all. It's a long story but in order to have clean urls had to do away with .htaccess and configure settings and httpd.conf instead.

I'm not sure what to do as the site is now live and I keep watching for member signups. At the same time if it is going to cause all sorts of problems, I want to fix them now before anyone joins.

My question is what could be forcing me to log out considering all of the above? the urls are all consistent.

Comment: You don't really provide a lot of specific details about your configuration (which OS, which kernel, etc.)  However, if it never happened before the upgrade, and now it happens after the upgrade, and you haven't changed anything else, obviously something went wrong with the upgrade.  Is it possible to roll back and try the upgrade again?

Comment: Sounds like you've messed up your rewrite rules also, clear all caches, delete browser cookies and check cookie_domain in settings.php to check those possibilities.

Comment: I have no control over what the vps provider does when their system fails. They have an auto upgrade system and all I know is it failed and they said they fixed it by switching the kernel I am on. I have contacted them again about it because it is through no fault of my own and I'm at a loss as to what to do. I can't switch back because I sorely need the memory. I guess will just have to wait and see what they say. I am not a programmer. I do not have skills to work out any of their system upgrades. Thank you very much for reply.

Comment: CentOs 6.3 on linux.